# Serverless with golang: 'make' is not recognized as a command

Tags: gnu-make

I am following [this tutorial](https://serverless.com/blog/framework-example-golang-lambda-support/) to create lambda functions using golang, but I get stuck at the `make` command where I get: `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I installed serverless using `npm install -g serverless` and I have node v8.9.4 and I'm running this on windows' cmd

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, you are missing [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). I'm not sure if there's a build available for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing `make` which has nothing to do with the serverless framework itself.

There's a [make for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)